# Recover .VMDK from ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I cannot even believe this happened, please tell me i can recover ;-(

I have a vm that had virtual disks spread over 2 datastores.

In windows 2003 i was using this virtual disk to as part of a dynamic disk. The system allowed me to delete this disk while the vm was running.

Is there anyway to recover?

Answer (score 1):

You can call OnTrack:

http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1015413

There is also some stuff you can try for free, but you risk losing your data:

http://crucialsecurityblog.harris.com/2011/06/08/virtual-machine-data-recovery-using-the-open-vmfs-driver/

Good luck, VMFS is a beast.